# Delete messages from specifc user using Discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py, message

I wanted to create a clear command where if example .clear @user#0000 100 it will clear the last 100 messages @user#0000 sent. Here is my code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=1):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    @clear.error
    async def clear_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send('Sorry, you are missing the ``MANAGE_MESSAGES`` permission to use this command.')
```

This code i provided only deletes depeneding how many messages will be deleted in a channel. I want to make a code where the bot will delete messages from a specific user. If this is possible, please let me know. I will use the code as future reference. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `check` kwarg to purge messages from specific user:

```py
from typing import Optional 

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, member: Optional[discord.Member], amount: int = 1):
    def _check(message):
        if member is None:
            return True
        else:
            if message.author != member:
                return False
            _check.count += 1
            return _check.count <= amount
    _check.count = 0
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1 if member is None else 1000, check=_check)
```

Comment: I want to do like a normal clear command where .clear clears the last messages and .clear @user#0000 clears the user's last messages, i get your code but is it possible to implement both functionability into a single command?

Comment: Understandable, I edited my answer. Check it out and try it, please.

Comment: What i found out that, when i did the .clear comnand without mentioning any users, it did clear messages normally. When i did .clear @user#0000 5, 5 then checks the last 5 messages sent and only deletes the @user#0000's messages in that range.

Comment: Additional info, i edited the limit amount (limit=amount+1) to also delete the message i entered the command, so the range of last messages sent without including the command i sent.

Comment: Ok, see the answer again. I edited it.

Comment: When i try to do .clear @user#0000 amount, It returned UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Comment: @danielmike293, Check again, please.

Comment: It worked. The code is little slow but it still worked.