# How can I delete messages sent by a specific user within a specific channel using Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate post but I've searched around and can't find anything on how to do this specifically.

I'm trying to create a Discord bot which can delete messages sent by a specific author, in a specific channel, but also checks previously sent messages.

At the moment I have the below, which adds new messages from chosen user to a list, checks if they're duplicates and if they are, deletes them.

I want to know:

A: How can I make this bot Channel specific

B: Can I have this program check old messages in that channel too and also delete them if they're duplicates?

Thanks in advance for any help and if any further info required, please let me know.

```
import discord

TOKEN = ('MY_TOKEN_LIVES_HERE')
client = discord.Client()

messagesSeen = []

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "News_Bot" in str(message.author):
        if message.content in messagesSeen:
            await message.delete()
        else:
            messagesSeen.append(message.content)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334104/16513476)

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401484/delete-messages-from-specifc-user-using-discord-py) appears to be another alternative. You can customise the `check` function to append the message content to the list, and obviously to perform any checks necessary. **Note**: If either of the two posts linked in this thread answer your question, feel free to mark your question as a duplicate. If not, please [edit] your post to include why these wouldn't work. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364513/16177247) for how to flag your own question as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do both of those things. Since you are using on_message event you can just use message.channel to also check that channel for previously sent messages. I would also advise to change `news_bot` to the ID of the bot. The thing is one you implement this and clear the channel history for those messages, it won't be necessary anymore as the bot will catch the messages as soon as they are sent. So the message history is kind of a one time thing, which you can just create a cmd and run it in that channel.

```py
messagesSeen = []

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if 1234345 is message.author.id:
          if message.content in messagesSeen:
               await message.delete()
               async for message in message.channel.history(limit=100):
                    if message.content in messagesSeen:
                         await message.delete()
          else:
               messagesSeen.append(message.content)
```